# Hexadecimal and ASCII give different SHA3 hashes, why?

Tags: sha-3

Hex and ASCII are encoded with the same binary code. Why is it that a message in ASCII and the same message in hexadecimal produce different hashes?

For example, the message `helping strangers over the internet is fun!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!` gives the hash `8029b81d7b1c01460710c855651d2f44062e57fca135987a8558f30d0264e07bea1be37e759bd9059b11758be47bef473e9691526acda84089d10415e327ef7a`,

while a hex of the message, `68656c70696e6720737472616e67657273206f7665722074686520696e7465726e65742069732066756e21212121212121212121212121212121212121212121` gives another hash, `d19bf1494bd6a3f71794dd5a07e83fde48147ab0e3736348af61e73fcddfc2733ba6d89740d3d99667dff9bed3ce1a61ad6215b4cfdfdb09eaf86b1d20280ce1`

*hashes via https://emn178.github.io/online-tools/keccak_512.html*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are calling hex is actually an ascii encoded, hex encoded string. In other words, it is something like `ascii(hex(string))`. In the other case you are just passing the ascii string.

Put another way, the tool you are using is expecting an ascii string. So by typing `686564` and so on, you are ascii encoding the hex encoded string.

So it makes sense that you are getting a different output. Note that this will happen with all hash functions, not just SHA3.